# Disable semitransparent hidden file icons

Tags: icon, macos

I have enabled hidden file visibility on OS X El Capitan 10.11, and the files are semitransparent. Is there a way to make them solid like all other files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chflags` to remove hidden flag from files you need:

```
chflags nohidden YourFile
```

Use this command with `YourFile` replaced with your file to change the file flag to no hidden.
Files and folders with `.` prefix will remain hidden.

Comment: I am not wanting to disable the hidden status; just the semitransparent icon that hidden files have.